# Silverlight Test without opening browser

Tags: silverlight-3.0

Is there any way to run Silverlight tests without opening the browser? It takes some time to open the browser. if you are doing TDD, you may not like it.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think so.
for Silverlights Sandbox has to be astablished to test apainst and the sandbox does life in the browser , I can´t see a way to achiev this.

Regards Ren

Answer (score 0):

You can test the Out Of Browser (OOB) version of your application instead.  To do this, add a call to Application.Install() within your application, run it, and then in Visual Studio debug the Silverlight project itself rather than the ASP.NET project.

Once installed, you can also run the OOB version of the application from the command-line using "sllauncher.exe".  To get the right parameters for sllauncher, look at the properties of the shortcut the installer creates for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can use the sllauncher.exe - it still runs in using an IEFrame - hence effectively still uses a browser to host the SL sandbox. Sure, you won't see the browser in the regular sense.